# Is it possible to set conditional environment variables in travis?

Tags: travis-ci

I am running on travis on 5 versions of nodeJS, .travis.yml is ....

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 5.0
  - 4.0
  - 0.12.7
  - 0.10.40
  - 0.10.36
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
script:
  - npm run travis
```

I want to set a travis environment variable for the run on nodeJS 5.0 only

something like this ...

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 5.0
    - env: POST_TO_COVERALLS=true
  - 4.0
  - 0.12.7
  - 0.10.40
  - 0.10.36
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
script:
  - npm run travis
```

but this is invalid ... anyone know how to do this ...

1 - Preferably, via .travis.yml

2 - If not, through the travis web application

I KNOW HOW TO DO THIS VIA CODE - But can it be done through travis?

Thanks all

Comment: i see from the travis documentation i could rely on ... TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER environment variable but i would prefer to create my own environment variable - thanks if anyone has the solution

Comment: TRAVIS_NODE_VERSION sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the matrix to explicitly include the one "5.0" build where your environment variable is set to true (see [documentation on explicitly including builds](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Explicity-Including-Builds)).

It would be something like the following

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 4.0
  - 0.12.7
  - 0.10.40
  - 0.10.36
env:
  POST_TO_COVERALLS=false
matrix:
    include:
       - node_js: 5.0
         env: POST_TO_COVERALLS=true
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
script:
  - npm run travis
```

Comment: Great solution, sadly I've implemented via code now but I am convinced this would work given the documentation you linked to and, time permitting, intend to switch to this approach given the chance, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Newly introduced [Travis build stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/) combined with some YML inheritance and and some hacking around assigning the Bash variable can be very handy for this:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Tests
      script: # run tests
    - script: # run more tests
    - &deploy-stuff
      stage: Deploy
      if: branch != master
      env:
      - ENV=$(if [ "$SOMETHING" = "thing" ]; then echo ${TRAVIS_BRANCH//\//-}; else echo "staging"; fi)
      script: # do some things before deploy
      deploy:
      - provider: script
        skip_cleanup: true
        script: echo $ENV
        on:
          all_branches: true
          condition: $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "devel" || $SOMETHING = "thing"
    - <<: *deploy-stuff
      if: branch = master
      env:
      - ENV="production"
      deploy:
      - provider: script
        skip_cleanup: true
        script: echo $ENV
        on:
          branch: master
```