# Travis configuration conditional environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, build, yaml, travis-ci

Inside of the travis configuration file, I have some environment variables defined like those:

```
env:
  SERVICE_URL=xxx
  SERVICE_VERSION=1.1.1
  TEST_CLUSTER=yyy
```

and I also want to add another environment variable if the travis build type is `pull_request`. Is there a way to do it?

What I mean is something like that (I couldn't find syntactically correct version)

```
env:
  if: type = pull_request
    LIVE_SERVICE_TEST=true
```

Comment: In YAML, the scalar `if` doesn't have any special meaning. YAML also doesn't know how to parse the scalar "type = pull_request LIVE_SERVICE_TEST=true",  Even though your input has a newline within that scalar, that will passed on to the application as a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some research on [conditional stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/#conditional-stages) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33758552/8304905), your solution might include something like the following:

```
matrix:
  include:
      if: type = pull_request
      env: LIVE_SERVICE_TEST=true
```

Check the documentation of Travis on [Conditional Builds, Stages and Jobs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/)